# Low rank approximation of binary valued matrix

Tags: matrix, binary-data, svd, approximation, linear-algebra

How does one get the low rank approximation of binary matrix? Is the low rank approximation also a binary matrix?

Note - Here binary matrix just means that any entry of the matrix can either be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

A naive approach might be using a plain ol' SVD with thresholds. Choose the thresholds that maximize classification accuracy, or some other sensitivity/specificity tradeoff.

Thresholding might up the rank, but it begs the question of why one would need to a low rank approximation of a binary matrix. Usually, low rank approximations are convenient for scale development and identification of subscales which is *strongly* based on assumptions about additive variance (this holds for normally distributed random variables but *not* Bernoulli random variables).

To me, I would consider creating separate models for the marginal cell counts as well as the odds ratios in a log linear model describing the assocations. That would create a large number of parameters, obviously. If I wanted something that were computationally more efficient and "easier to digest" I might consider using sparse estimation with a LASSO or other tool.

Comment: And what about this part of the OP: "Is the low rank approximation also a binary matrix?"

Comment: @amoeba, no, it would not be binary. They apply thresholds at the end

Comment: "Thresholding might up the rank, but it begs the question of why one would need to a low rank approximation of a binary matrix." The classic example of SVD approximations to binary matrices is the Netflix Prize data: an enormous matrix of users and movies can be decomposed into rich feature vectors describing genres of movies and the preferences of users using SVD.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to compute the Hamming distance between data vectors and then use this as a pairwise distance metric. If the number of dimensions is much larger than the number of data points, this may make sense. I am not sure if this reduces rank for certain, but it's a more compact representation of the structure.